# Query multiple colums from a table and display it in viewlist

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I want to display sms sender address and body in list view after querying from my database
i saved my sms data in this way

```
enter ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", sms.getOriginatingAddress().toString() );
values.put("date", mydate);
values.put("address", sms.getOriginatingAddress().toString() );
values.put("date", mydate);
values.put("body", sms.getMessageBody().toString());

db.insert("datatable", null, values);
```

now i want to retrive data in such a way to display in listview as "senderaddress" and "body"

i am trying with following code

```
 String[] arrayColumns = new String[]{"address","body"};
        int[] arrayViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.textViewSMSSender,R.id.textViewMessageBody};
```

problem comes here in retriving data

```
 Cursor cursor;
cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
```

how can i make it to fit in below code

```
  SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_each_item, cursor, arrayColumns, arrayViewIDs);


listViewSMS.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try getting data using this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("datatable", new String[] {"address", "body"}, 
                null, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: I am getting sms straight in my receiver no sms is going in the default inbox.
all permissions are already added read write...

Comment: i didn't get you. do you want to show messages from inbox or you want to show from your own database?

Comment: from my own data base

Comment: problam is here

Cursor cursor;
cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);

this query must be different as i have no provider "uri"

Comment: but why do you want data from inbox if it is saved in your DB. uri will get data from SMS Inbox.

Comment: sms are received in my own database they never go to the default sms inbpx or default inbox database.

Comment: yea that's right. so why are you calling URI of inbox. call your database table and fetch data from that.

Comment: I think i have managed to do it using this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial)

rest will be validated on running